# Running a python file showing image in google colab

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

I want to run a python file in google colab. The file will also show an image in a loop. But whatever I do, I am not able to show the image.

```
cam = cv2.VideoCapture('etcs/waste_2.mp4')
ret_val, image = cam.read()
while i<50:
    ret_val, image = cam.read()
    i+=1
    image,new_centers = TfPoseEstimator.draw_humans(image, humans, imgcopy=False)

    logger.debug('show+')
    cv2.putText(image,
                "FPS: %f" % (1.0 / (time.time() - fps_time)),
                (10, 10),  cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,
                (0, 255, 0), 2)
    cv2_imshow(image)
    imshow(np.asarray(image))
    plt.show()
    sleep(1)
    
    fps_time = time.time()
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == 27:
        break
    logger.debug('finished+')
```

Output:

[image: no image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the command 'run' instead of '!python' to execute .py file.
[image]